# Get one value from mySQL database with PHP and save as variable

Tags: php, mysql

I have a SQL database containing the columns `name` and `text`. How can I get only the `text` with the `name` and save that as a variable using PHP?

I've tried several code snippets from other people but none worked.

```
$sql = "SELECT text FROM texts WHERE INSTR(name, '{$name}')";
$result = $db->query($sql);
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
$var=echo $row["name"];
echo $var;
```

Comment: Show what you tried. This is one of the most basic operations there is, it's hard to understand how they couldn't have worked.

Comment: Show your code. You can find thousands of examples of this on the web. If something doesn't work we need to see it to help

Comment: Please be aware of increasing chances to give you correct and precise answer – share you code, give steps to reproduce or/and test cases/data will increase your chances to get an good answer soon

Comment: Don't use `echo` with the assignment. Is `$db` and `$name` set? You should really use parameterized queries. I have never used the `INSTR` function, what is the columns value, and the variable value?

Comment: **WARNING**: This has some severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) because user data is used inside the query. Whenever possible use **prepared statements**. These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.
**NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or any user data directly in your query.

Comment: Note: If you're using `INSTR` you've probably got a schema problem here. Those sorts of operations cannot be indexed and end up being painfully slow due to table scans on non-trivial amounts of data. Why can't you do a direct match on `name=?`?

Comment: @tadman doing a direct match here seems to be good idea. I'll try this! I just started using PHP and mySQL so I'm not familiar with my possibilites in this case.

Comment: Nothing wrong with just getting started, just be sure to look for best practices and follow those until you understand more about how this all fits together. [PHP the Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) could help as a guide to get going.

Answer (score -1):

Following is standard way execute query and store in php variable.

Query with mysqli

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "username", "password", "database");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$sqliQuery= "select name, text from tableName";
if ($result = $mysqli->query($sqliQuery)) {    
     while ($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
        $firstname = $row->name;
        $middlename = $row->text;
    }
    $result->close();
}
else
{
   echo 'something went wrong';
}
```

Comment: when using `mysql_query` PHP Storm says that its deprecated

Comment: It's deprecated and you should use PDO or mysqli, that is why I post an answer with mysql and mysqli solutions

Comment: mysql_* functions have been removed in PHP7

Comment: You shouldnt have the `mysql_` example. OP is using `mysqli` don't send them in the wrong direction.

Comment: @Chris  Please refer my answer twice then please comment with this. I did not redirect on wrong direction. He asked me and I gave an answer to him. So please before post any negative comment, please read whole conversation. I did not do anything wrong. I gave just an answer of his question

Comment: so I inserted your code but I only want to get one specific value 
for example:
`function createrecipetext ($bun)` and then search in the field `name` for the corresponding `text`and save that.

Comment: Why even acknowledge the existence of `mysql_*`? OP is using mysqli.

Comment: Can you get rid of `mysql_query` in this answer? Not only is it extremely misleading, but it's something the PHP community has worked hard to get rid of.